# Prevent "Dialog" Activity from interacting with background activity when clicking outside bounds

Tags: android, android-activity, android-styles

I'm creating an activity that looks like a dialog.

**Here is the style:**

```
<style name="TablesDialogActivity" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/frame_background_left</item>
</style>
```

**Here is the activity onCreate():**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
        getWindow().setFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH, LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
}
```

**And also inside the activity touch interceptor:**

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE) {
        finish();
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It pretty much works, activity finishes on touch outside dialog bounds, but it also interacts with buttons on the background activity which is bad. Documentation on the `onTouchEvent` says that you should return true if you consumed the touch event. I return true, but it doesn't seem that way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650246/how-to-cancel-an-dialog-themed-like-activity-when-touched-outside-the-window/5831214#5831214 
it's good answer)

Comment: have you looked on my code? if you did you'd know it's taken from there.

Comment: You can find my solution to this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701915/can-we-interact-with-background-activity-when-displaying-a-dialog-over-it-in-and

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note, that you will need the whole code from the question too.**

In addition to my solution **inside background activity** (or just base activity of your application) I added:

```
private FrameLayout touchInterceptor;

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    if (touchInterceptor.getParent() == null) {
        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).addView(touchInterceptor);
    }
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    ((ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content)).removeView(touchInterceptor);
    super.onResume();
}
```

And in the `onCreate()`:

```
    // For intercepting clicks from dialog like activities
    touchInterceptor = new FrameLayout(this);
    touchInterceptor.setClickable(true);
```

Now works like a charm! :)

Answer (score 0):

hm..interesting) 
in my app i use fragments, so i use DialogFragment instead of Dialog. 
i created safe show dialog method

```
private static void showDialog(FragmentManager fragmentManager, String dialogTag, BeamDialogData data) {

        FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        ft.commit();
        fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions();
        Fragment prev = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(dialogTag);
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        BeamDialog beamDialog = new BeamDialog();
        beamDialog.setData(data);
        beamDialog.show(fragmentManager, dialogTag);
    }

    public static void showDialogSafe(final FragmentManager fragmentManager, final String dialogTag, 
            final BeamDialogData data, Handler handler) {
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                    showDialog(fragmentManager, dialogTag, data);
            }           
        });     
    }
```

BeamDialog is my custom DialogFragment 
so there are not backgrounds clicks) 
i hope, that this will useful for you)

Comment: The whole thing is about doing it in the activity and not in the DialogFragment