# Allow interaction with parent activity in a transparent full screen DialogFragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

I have a fullscreen dialog fragment that has transparent areas. I'd like for the user to be able to interact with the other fragments in the background in these transparent areas. I've tried setting the `FLAG_NO_TOUCH_MODAL` field as follows.

```
view.post(new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    Window dialogWindow = getDialog().getWindow();
    dialogWindow.setFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    view.invalidate();
  }
  });
```

This only works when the DialogFragment is not full screen(ie, the dialog wraps the visible elements). I need for it to be fullscreen and have the transparent areas. Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Comment: You can find my solution to this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16701915/can-we-interact-with-background-activity-when-displaying-a-dialog-over-it-in-and